# Is there ever a reason to use mixed slashes in URLs?

Tags: url

A site I just started working on has a preponderance of links that start with 
`https:\/\/` or `http:\/\/` - before I ask whether this is the result of some find/replace procedure run amok, can anyone explain whether there's a good reason to use this?

Probably a very noob question, thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [URL specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), the backslash is considered an unsafe character and needs to be encoded:

> Octets must be encoded if they have no corresponding graphic 
>   character within the US-ASCII coded character set, if the use of the 
>   corresponding character is **unsafe** [...]

And:

> Other characters are **unsafe** because gateways and other transport
>   agents are known to sometimes modify    such characters. These
>   characters are "{", "}", "|", **"\"**, "^", "~", "[", "]", and "`".